Prevent selenium chrome (Remote WebDriver) + NetworkInterceptor upgrading http to https
I'm using selenium hub with a node-chromium instance, like so:
version: '3.8'
name: 'selenium-feature-extractor-dev'
services:
  selenium-hub:
    image: seleniarm/hub:4.18.1-20240327
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
  selenium-chrome:
    image: seleniarm/node-chromium:123.0-chromedriver-123.0-grid-4.18.1-20240327
    shm_size: 2gb
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
      - SE_NODE_MAX_SESSIONS=10
      - SE_OPTS=--grid-url http://localhost:4444

I'm also using a NetworkInterceptor to enforce certain headers, like so:
    try (NetworkInterceptor ignored = addHeadersToRequests(driver, headers)) {
       ...
    }

    private NetworkInterceptor addHeadersToRequests(WebDriver driver, Map<String, String> headers) {
        if (driver instanceof HasDevTools && headers != null) {
            Filter filter = next -> req -> {
                headers.forEach((key, value) -> {
                    req.removeHeader(key);
                    req.addHeader(key, value);
                });
                return next.execute(req);
            };
            return new NetworkInterceptor(driver, filter);
        }
        return null;
    }

When I request an http site, at some point along the line it's being upgraded to an https request, and returning an empty html page.
The first time I see this in the logs is here:
2024-04-03T15:51:27.558+01:00  INFO 26651 --- [ CDP Connection] o.openqa.selenium.devtools.Connection    : <- {"method":"Fetch.requestPaused","params":{"requestId":"interception-job-1.0","request":{"url":"https://mysite.pro/","method":"GET","headers":{"Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7","Accept-Language":"en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8","Upgrade-Insecure-Requests":"1","User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"},"initialPriority":"VeryHigh","referrerPolicy":"strict-origin-when-cross-origin"},"frameId":"D3EC8B769B07AD51B5752B137EF1916B","resourceType":"Document"},"sessionId":"B0A124EC0331A37418F1136BB92D1F32"}
2024-04-03T15:51:27.558+01:00  INFO 26651 --- [ CDP Connection] o.openqa.selenium.devtools.Connection    : Method Fetch.requestPaused called with 2 callbacks available
2024-04-03T15:51:27.559+01:00  INFO 26651 --- [ CDP Connection] o.openqa.selenium.devtools.Connection    : Matching Fetch.requestPaused with Fetch.requestPaused
2024-04-03T15:51:27.563+01:00  INFO 26651 --- [ CDP Connection] o.openqa.selenium.devtools.Connection    : Calling callback for Fetch.requestPaused using org.openqa.selenium.devtools.idealized.Network$$Lambda/0x00000003017dd230@21408fe2 being passed org.openqa.selenium.devtools.v122.fetch.model.RequestPaused@1b7b7141
2

If I don't use the NetworkInterceptor to apply the headers, the request doesn't get upgraded - it correctly requests and retrieves the http site.
This leads me to believe it's related to the NetworkInterceptor, and not any other component.
How can I prevent the request upgrade? Not every site is on https, I don't want that decision to be made for me.
For info: I've set the ChromeOptions to allow insecure certs along with these switches:
            "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
            "--ignore-certificate-errors",
            "--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled",
            "--log-level=DEBUG",
            "--whitelisted-ips",
            "--disable-gpu",
            "--disable-software-rasterizer",
            "--verbose",
            "--remote-allow-origins=*",
            "--ignore-urlfetcher-cert-requests",
            "--allow-running-insecure-content"


looks like your headers has: "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests":"1"  Can you show code that defines your headers?  Also note that some servers will automatically upgrade all requests.  (it's a fairly common setting)

That was actually being set by default. Even if I override that to send "0" it still happened.

Turns out that this was a bug with selenium 4.18.1
According to the developer who fixed it (/created the workaround) on our side:

Selenium doesn't handle requests that failed to get a response (e.g. timed out or failed to connect) properly, instead returning a 200 response to Chrome so that it erroneously continues processing the page.
The workaround is to intercept the processing and return a special PROCEED_WITH_REQUEST response, which causes Selenium to not overwrite the response before returning it to Chrome. This allows Chrome to behave as if network interception wasn't enabled.

In this case, the request was being upgraded, and an error was being returned (because there was no site on https), and selenium was hiding that.
Now it isn't, so the fallback to http happens as it should.

    private NetworkInterceptor addHeadersToRequests(WebDriver driver, Map<String, String> headers) {
        if (driver instanceof HasDevTools && headers != null) {
            Filter filter = next -> req -> {
                headers.forEach((key, value) -> {
                    req.removeHeader(key);
                    req.addHeader(key, value);
                });
                return next.execute(req);
            };
            // FIXME: We should be using NetworkInterceptor(driver, filter) here but can't until Selenium fix their bug
            DevTools tools = ((HasDevTools) driver).getDevTools();
            tools.createSessionIfThereIsNotOne(driver.getWindowHandle());
            BugFixedNetwork network = new BugFixedNetwork(tools);
            network.interceptTrafficWith(filter);
        }
        return null;
    }


// This is a workaround for a bug in the Selenium 4.18.1, which doesn't handle requests that fail to connect
// e.g. due to DNS failures or timeouts.
private static class BugFixedNetwork extends v122Network {

    public BugFixedNetwork(DevTools devTools) {
        super(devTools);
    }

    @Override
    public Either<HttpRequest, HttpResponse> createSeMessages(RequestPaused pausedReq) {
        if (pausedReq.getResponseErrorReason().isPresent() && pausedReq.getResponseStatusCode().isEmpty()) {
            return Either.right(PROCEED_WITH_REQUEST);
        }
        return super.createSeMessages(pausedReq);
    }
}


